# Rutas administrarles en vue router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli

Hola estoy desarrollando un dashborad gestionable.

Mi problema es que un usuario solo puede ver ciertos módulos. El que dice esto es el backend. Entonces al final:

1. El usuario A tiene acceso a todo.
2. El usuario B solo tiene acceso a las estadísticas.

Tengo para esto en vue router.

```
const routes = [  
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: () => import('@/views/Home.vue'),
    beforeEnter: AuthGuard.auth,
    meta: {
      layout: 'dashboard'
    }
  },
 
 {
    path: '/estadisticas',
    name: 'estadisticas',
    component: () => import('@/views/estadisticas.vue'),

    meta: {
      layout: 'dashboard',
      auth: true
    }
  }
]
```

El problema que presento es que cuando el usuario hace login. El login le manda las rutas a las que tiene acceso. Si el usuario intentara pedir algo que a lo que no tiene permiso regresa el backend un error 401.

Sin embargo yo no se como hacer hacer que vue router solo tenga disponibles las rutas que le corresponden a un usuario.

Intente colocar las rutas en tiempo de ejecucion:

```
      this.$router.options. routes.push({
        omponent: "hola.js",
        meta: { layout: "blank" },
        name: "hole",
        path: "/holi"
      });
```

Pero esto no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

en el index de vue router tu puedes ejecutar un función, para que dependiendo de alguna condición que tenga el usuario solo pueda acceder a algunas urls, en caso contrario lo rediriges a otra pantalla, en este caso por ejemplo, vitrifico si el usuario esta logueado para que pueda acceder a la url, si no se dirige a login:

```
Vue.use(Router)

const routes = [...mis rutas....]

const rutas = new Router({
  routes: routes,
  mode: 'history'
})

// metodo para enviar urls privadas a login
rutas.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // verificamos todas la rutas
  rutas.options.routes.forEach((route) => {
    // si coincide con una ruta y tiene propiedad secure verificamos login
    if (to.matched[0].path === route.path && route.secure) {
      if (!state.isLoggedIn) {
        return next('/login')
      }
    }
  })
  // curso normal del proceso
  next()
})

export default rutas
```